# Issue booting Linux Mint from Live CD?

Tags: linux, boot, bios, grub

I had Windows 8 and Linux Mint 15 dual booted on my laptop. When I first installed Linux, I wasn't able to load into because the grub would not show. To fix this, I used boot-repair from a Live CD. This time, I updated to Windows 8.1 and it showed a watermark telling me my secure boot wasn't configured properly. I then went and enabled secure boot (BIOS) and I believe it was after that that the Grub would not show once again. I tried to boot from a Linux CD again but when I try, it gives me the following errors:

```
error: failure reading sector 0x0 from 'hd1'
error: you need to load the kernel first.

Press any key to continue...
```

Before, it was giving me an error with sector 0x6d200  or something instead of 0x0.
I am completely unsure of what to do. I do not know what other details to give except that this my have happened after I enabled secure boot, and I actually clicked reset to default setting so I am unsure if any other settings were changed in the BIOS menu.

Comment: hi1 suggests your hard drive. have you checked the boot order in the bios?

Comment: EFI Boot? You may have to reinstall grub.

Comment: @bryan Legacy boot order shows: Notebook Hard Drive, Internet CD Drive, USB Diskette on Key/USB Hard Disk, USB CD ROM Drive, ! Network Adapter in that order

Comment: @Grizly That's what I tried to do but I can't even boot into the Live CD

Comment: You'd need to change the boot order to get to the liveCD (based on that list), I googled that first error, and it seems common to every distro! Can you turn off UEFI for the DVD drive? This might help (once its fixed: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_EFI_mode)

Comment: @Grizly The Legacy Boot order is actually disabled

Comment: @Grizly put the CD Rom first on my boot order but that wasn't the issue, since even after I boot from CD and try to Start Linux Mint, it gave the same errors but with sector 0x6d200 instead of 0x0

Comment: Have you turned "Secure Boot" off again?

Comment: @Grizly Yes, and I changed it into legacy mode.  This allowed me to run the live linux mint cd and reinstall grub using boot-repair. Although I am able to start both linux and windows, the problem persists: I am unable to run the live CD when I changed it back to UEFI mode.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off Secure Boot.

Linux Mint doesn't support it yet.

Comment: I turned it off, the Live CD would give me the same error.

Comment: You commented above:  "I changed it into legacy mode. This allowed me to run the live linux mint cd and reinstall grub using boot-repair" Is this ambiguous? I don't understand the problem then.

Comment: So, im having this issue too on an Hp Arch Linux laptop, runing system rescue cd.  error: failure reading from sector 0x...... from cd0, you need to load the kernel first. And thats exactly why im loading the cd in the first place. STUCK. Answers Please?

Comment: Hi Brian, I'm sure this isn't the place for this, but you can use something like http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03653226 but in reverse to disable Secure Boot from your device.